# Get id of feature selected

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How does one get the id of the feature that has been selected or deselected? I need to call a specific function passing a feature or it's id every time a feature is selected or deselected. Something along the lines of:

```js
selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select( {
  layers: layers
} );

map.getInteractions().extend( [ selectInteraction ] );

selectInteraction.on( "select", function ( evt ) {

  if( evt.selected.length > 0 ) {
    onFeatureSelect( evt.selected[ 0 ] );
  } else {
    onFeatureUnselect( evt.deselected[ 0 ] );
  }
});
```

Comment: You may use this method - http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#getId

Comment: Thanks Jonatas. The problem is that I don't what feature to call that on. I need the feature before I can get its id. Is there a way to access the feature that was selected via the interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
selectInteraction.on('select', function(evt){
    if(evt.selected.length > 0){
        console.info('selected: ' + evt.selected[0].getId());

    }
});
```